# why browser is adding extra backward slashes to the json Response and also JSON array length is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the way  i am making a callback request to the server for a JSON Value

```
$(document).on('click', '.currentOrderRow', function(event ) {
var orderid = $(this).attr("id_data");

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'/OMS/oms1/getOrderdetails?orderid='+orderid,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function (response) {
    alert(response.json_value.length);
            console.log('response is'+JSON.stringify(response));

        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Into error ');
        }
    });


});
```

I am observing while the JSON response which is shown in the server console is having slashes within in ()

```
{
    "json_value": "[{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9876543210\",\"SurCharges\":\"50\",\"vendorname\":\"VC4 Raj\",\"contact_email\":\"rajk@gmail.com\",\"count\":\"0\",\"discount_div\":\"10%\",\"itemid\":\"188\",\"strikeprice_cutoff\":\"90\",\"name\":\"Popcorn Plain salted\",\"contact_address\":\"Kukatpally, Hyderabad\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"email_id\":\"raj@hmail.com\",\"date_time\":\"14:10:37\",\"toppings\":[{\"name\":\"Quantity  1\",\"value\":[\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce 10 ML\",\"None\",\"None\",\"None\",\"None\",\"None\",\"None\",\"None\"]}],\"screen\":\"SCR-3\",\"seat_num\":\"D12\",\"customer_name\":\"Ganesh\",\"image\":\"images/icon-print.png\",\"contact_person\":\"Kiran\",\"item_description\":\"Item description\",\"vendor_id\":\"9\",\"crusts\":[],\"Vat\":\"70\",\"customer_mobil\":\"9090987878\",\"price\":\"115\",\"mobile_number\":\"1234567898\",\"ServicesCharges\":\"50\",\"orderid\":\"14101337\"},{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9876543210\",\"SurCharges\":\"50\",\"vendorname\":\"VC4 Raj\",\"contact_email\":\"rajk@gmail.com\",\"count\":\"0\",\"discount_div\":\"10Rs\",\"itemid\":\"194\",\"strikeprice_cutoff\":\"110\",\"name\":\"Popcorn Regular   300 ML Fountain Apple\",\"contact_address\":\"Kukatpally, Hyderabad\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"email_id\":\"raj@hmail.com\",\"date_time\":\"14:10:37\",\"toppings\":[{\"name\":\"Quantity  1\",\"value\":[\"Chocolate\",\"Vanila\"]}],\"screen\":\"SCR-3\",\"seat_num\":\"D12\",\"customer_name\":\"Ganesh\",\"image\":\"images/icon-print.png\",\"contact_person\":\"Kiran\",\"item_description\":\"Item description\",\"vendor_id\":\"9\",\"crusts\":[{\"name\":\"Quantity  1\",\"value\":[\"Butter scotch\"]}],\"Vat\":\"70\",\"customer_mobil\":\"9090987878\",\"price\":\"275\",\"mobile_number\":\"1234567898\",\"ServicesCharges\":\"50\",\"orderid\":\"14101337\"}]"
}
```

And why the length is being shown as 1525 ??

Because the above JSON is consisting of two values within it ?? (Starting from contact_phone_no each is a new record )

Comment: What do you get using `console.log(response);`?

Comment: the back slash is used to escape the double quote in JSON see: http://json.org/ "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes"

Comment: Your response consists of an object with one property. That property has a value: a string (which seems to be JSON). You seem to be expecting it to be an array. This has nothing to do with the browser, it is what the server is sending.

Comment: Try with `alert(JSON.parse(response.json_value).length);`

Comment: @Satpal With your statement i am getting length as 2 .

Comment: @Quentin has provide you the correct explanation, so you have solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug on the server side. Instead of sending you a JSON object graph (i.e. nested JSON objects), it sends you a single string which contains objects in JSON format. Or to put it another way: It send you JSON inside of JSON.

To parse the data, you need this code:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.json_value);
```

Or fix the bug on the server side.